# is it possible to create views in Application class?

Tags: android

i am using Application class for all starting services.is it possible to create alert dialog in application class? i created a dialog it shows error

```
android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application
```

this is my code

```
public class Alertpplication extends Application {
 public void onCreate() {
     if (isWifiConnected()) {
    //do some operations
    }  
    else{
 {AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(AlertApplication.this)
            .create();

        // Setting Dialog Title
        alertDialog.setTitle("Alert");



        // Setting Dialog Message
        alertDialog.setMessage("No Wifi Connection");

        // Setting Icon to Dialog
        // alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.connection_error);

        // Setting OK Button

        alertDialog.setButton("Connectivity Settings",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        // Write your code here to execute after dialog closed
                        // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        // "You clicked on OK",
                        // Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                        startActivity(new Intent(
                                Settings.ACTION_WIRELESS_SETTINGS));


                    }
                });
       alertDialog.show();

    }
 }


}
```

Comment: Could you add some code of how you try to create the alert dialog?

Comment: I am not sure: is `LibreApplication.this` the same as `getApplicationContext()`?

Comment: The application does not have a window. You should use an Activity to show your dialog.

Comment: @Karakuri Really? Showing a `PopupWindow` from `Application` class works fine.

Comment: Try calling `alertDialog.show()` with some delay. You can use `Handler#postDelayed(...)` for that.

Comment: @SaschaM78 - the question was not if a particular method would work, but rather if a given desire is *possible*.  No code is needed to answer that.

Comment: @Vikram i have changed the this function..

Comment: @Karakuri i can use activity for showing dialog.but the application is only one class which will run one time.its more suitable in my case

Comment: @Asthme Try showing the dialog after some delay.

Comment: @Vikram i don''t think so,it will solve the problem,when the application does not have window,how it will work later,do u think that it will get the window when activity starts?may be i need to find the way to add window in my application

Comment: @Asthme I don't know why, but the window token takes some time to initialize. Showing a dialog, even inside an Activity's onCreate(..) throws this exception. Anyway, try if you feel like. And its not like you can fetch a window from somewhere.

Comment: How is the user supposed to start your application if there's no Activity? You need an Activity that can be launched from the launcher; otherwise your app will never be launched and it will never run because newly installed apps are in a stopped state until the user launches them.